# vue router component variable undefined

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

hello im using router in my php page content tabs, when i first time enter the route variables undefined and change the route go back it works, when i enter from url same as not defined variable shows in vue dev extension?

> app.js

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: infotab,
    name: 'Info'
  },
  { path: '/characters', component: charactertab, name: 'home' },
  { path: '/watch', component: watchtab },
  { path: '/downloads', component: downloadtab }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
});

var tabb = new Vue({
 router,
 el: "#app",
}).$mount('#app');
```

> Template script

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      details: window.infos,
      characters: window.characters,
      episodes: window.episodes,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

> single.blade.php

```
              <div data-v-20e267b2="" data-v-aaf71b06="" class="overview">
                <router-view></router-view>
              </div>
           </div>
<script>
window.infos = {!! json_encode($response) !!};
window.characters = {!! json_encode($apicharacters) !!};
window.episodes = {!! json_encode($episodes) !!};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's undefined because the properties on the `window` object are not being set.

Instead, you could move the

```
<script>
window.infos = {!! json_encode($response) !!};
window.characters = {!! json_encode($apicharacters) !!};
window.episodes = {!! json_encode($episodes) !!};
</script>
```

So it is within the HTML `<head>`. This will then set the properties and values before Vue starts up.